# Pivot table with custom values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have table say [**FIDDLE HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a363175d6fba4fb5f58b74d5acf9a416)

```
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
| id | year | sell | buy | own |
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
| 1  | 2016 | 9    | 2   | 10  |
| 1  | 2017 | 9    |     | 10  |
| 1  | 2018 |      | 2   | 10  |
| 2  | 2016 | 7    | 2   | 11  |
| 2  | 2017 | 2    |     |     |
| 2  | 2018 |      |     | 18  |
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
```

```sql
create table test(id varchar(20), year varchar(20), 
sell varchar(20), buy varchar(20), 
own varchar(20));

insert into test values('1', '2016','9','2','10' )
insert into test values('1', '2017','9',NULL,'10' )
insert into test values('1', '2018',NULL,'2','10' )
insert into test values('2', '2016','7','2','11' )
insert into test values('2', '2017','2',NULL,'17' )
insert into test values('2', '2018','5','2','18' )
```

I'm trying to `PIVOT` but instead of aggregate the values, i wanted to keep some letters if it is not null *(S-Sell,B-Buy,O-Own)*. If there are values for all columns for particular year then i need `S_B_O` for that year. If there are values only for sell and buy then `S_B` etc., so Expected output is

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| ID | 2016  | 2017 | 2018 |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 1  | S_B_O | S_O  | B_O  |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 2  | S_B_O | S    | O    |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

The closest i have got is using conditional aggrgarion( `MAX` and `concat`) instead of `PIVOT` but this is also giving null if any one is `NULL`. Please suggest a solution.

```
select ID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2016' AND sell is not null THEN 'S_' END + 
CASE WHEN Year = '2016' AND buy is not null THEN 'B_' END +
CASE WHEN Year = '2016' AND own is not null THEN 'O' END)
AS [2016],
MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2017' AND sell is not null THEN 'S_' END + 
CASE WHEN Year = '2017' AND buy is not null THEN 'B_' END +
CASE WHEN Year = '2017' AND own is not null THEN 'O' END)
AS [2017]
/* ......for all year */
from test
group by id
```

[FIDDLE HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a363175d6fba4fb5f58b74d5acf9a416)

Comment: `{Some String} + NULL = NULL` Use `CONCAT` which implicitly changes `NULL` values to `''`.

Comment: Sure @Larnu i will try that. Are there any better way of doing this? because sometimes i can't predict the no of years. I have to hardcode it for each year

Comment: You would have to use a dynamic pivot. That is a *very* different question, and there are literally 100's of examples on them on Stack Overflow.

Comment: But how can I use these letter(S_B_O) in dynamic pivot? Could you please redirect me to some reference page? @Larnu

Comment: [Google - Site:stackoverflow.com Dynamic Pivot SQL Server](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Dynamic+Pivot+SQL+Server); literally thousands of results.

Comment: It needs concat_ws

Comment: Not on 2012, @SteveC .

Comment: Yeah it needs an alternative or there are extra _'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CONCAT function, which will handle NULLs automatically.

```sql
select ID, 
CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2016' AND sell is not null THEN 'S_' END) , 
MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2016' AND buy is not null THEN 'B_' END) ,
MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2016' AND buy is not null THEN 'O' END))
AS [2016],
CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2017' AND sell is not null THEN 'S_' END) , 
MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2017' AND buy is not null THEN 'B_' END) ,
MAX(CASE WHEN Year = '2017' AND buy is not null THEN 'O' END))
AS [2017]
from test
group by id
```

```
+----+-------+------+
| ID | 2016  | 2017 |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | S_B_O | S_   |
|  2 | S_B_O | S_   |
+----+-------+------+
```

**UPDATE** Dynamic query. As @Larnu told, You should have asked this as separate question. You should not change the requirement.

```sql
DECLARE @lst_Years NVARCHAR(MAX) , @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @lst_Years = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Year]) 
            FROM test 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
(
select ID, [Year],
CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN  sell is not null THEN ''S_'' END) , 
MAX(CASE WHEN  buy is not null THEN ''B_'' END) ,
MAX(CASE WHEN buy is not null THEN ''O'' END))
AS [Value]
from test
group by id, [year]) as t
pivot
(
max(value) FOR YEAR IN (' + @lst_Years + ')
) as pvt'

EXEC(@query)
```

```
+----+-------+------+-------+
| ID | 2016  | 2017 | 2018  |
+----+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | S_B_O | S_   | B_O   |
|  2 | S_B_O | S_   | S_B_O |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be fine. Can I somehow make it dynamic? so that i dont want to hardcode for each year.

Comment: That should be a separate question, @Avinash , however, a quick search will give you 100's of examples.

Comment: @Avinash,  AS Larnu mentioned, that should be separate question. anyway, I have added dynamic query also to the answer.

Comment: @VenkataramanR. Could you please help me to remove those extra `_` at the end like `S_` to `S` if possible? I have tried so many ways and nothing is working. It seems to be easy in latest version but not finding anything in `2012` version

Comment: @Avinash, please ask separate question. changing it , will lead to confusion for future readers of this question.